# How to use the GET method in php to capture information needed for sql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a program to create an online forum and I am relatively new to php. 
I have used a while loop to display all topics created for discussion in a table. This reads my sql database and echoes out just fine:

```
        if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) >0 ) {
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) )
            {
                echo "<tr><th><p align = 'left'>"."Posted By ".$row['first_name']." " .$row['last_name']. " on ". $row['post_date']."<br/>";
                echo "<p style = 'color:#2208A1', align='left'>"."Subject:". $row['subject']."<br/><br/>";
                echo "Message: ". $row['message']."<br/>";
                echo "ID Number =  ". $row['post_id']."<br/>";
                echo "<p style='color:red;' align = 'right'>"."<a href='http://localhost/FirstCswkAttempts/2017%20Web%20Scenario_A2/cwk_addreply.php?post_id =" .$row['post_id']." '>Reply to Post."."</a></p>";
                "</tr></th>";                       
            }
        }
```

However,you can see that in the last line of code I try to concatenate the post_id number to the URL in the hope that I can use this information in another php file:

The code below shows my attempt to do just this. I use the GET method to capture post_id and insert it into another table in my database. If I use var_dump(`$_GET`); I get an empty array. Where am I going wrong??

```
  $q = "INSERT INTO responses(reply_owner, reply_text,reply_create_time,post_id) 
            VALUES (' ".$_POST['email']." ', ' ".$_POST["message"]."', now(),'".$_GET['post_id']."')";
    $r = mysqli_query ( $dbc, $q 

) ;
```

In response to comments, please find the form used to add posts to the topic:

```
            <h1>Reply to Thread</h1>
            <!--Display form-->
            <form action="cwk_reply_action.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <p><strong>Your email:<br><input name="email" type="text" size="55px" maxlength="100"></p>
            <p>Message:<br><textarea name="message" rows="5" cols="50px"></textarea></strong></p>
            <input type = "hidden" name = "post_id" value = "$_GET['post_id'] ">
            <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p></form>
```

Comment: Are you posting to `postHandler.php?post_id=1` or just `postHandler.php` ? I see where someone is sent to `cwk_addreply.php?post_id =" .$row['post_id']."` which presumably has the form. But I need to know what that form posts to.

Comment: `?post_id =" .$row['post_id']." '` try removing the spaces from the query string: `?post_id=" .$row['post_id']. "'`.

Comment: This is what you're getting: `Scenario_A2/cwk_addreply.php?post_id%20=5` from [your code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HHnFaz). The `%20` is an encoded space.

Comment: You've got all kinds of things wrong with your markup, and the code itself is error-prone (there is no reason to join to string like this: `echo "abc"."def";`). Here it is reformatted, with the first `<p>` tag closed, the extraneous concatenations and attribute-value spaces removed, and the `<tr>` and `<th>` fixed so they nest correctly: http://codepad.viper-7.com/W4nNXh

Comment: @Don't Panic  A good suggestion - my url reads .....php?post_id=5 rather than throwing %20 into the mix.  However, my array still reads empty and the record inserted into my sql database has a value of 0

Comment: Also, to your question, you're showing the link created to go to add a reply, and the snippet meant to add the reply to the database, but are missing the most important part: The form that posts to the page that contains the latter `INSERT` snippet.

Comment: @Jared Farrish Many thanks for the code and suggestions. As a newbie it is going to take me awhile to assimilate it all - which I am trying to do - just didnt want you to think Im not grateful by not replying or upvoting

Comment: In your insert statement, you are using values from `$_POST` and `$_GET`. I assume the url above sends you to a page with a form that submits to the script that executes the SQL query. On that form, add a hidden input and set its value to `$_GET['post_id']` when the form is displayed. Then you can just get all of your values for the query from `$_POST`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I would have suggested a hidden input based on the form markup (that we never got)

Comment: The form may not be complicated, but the problem you are dealing with here seems to involve an error passing a value from page 1 to page 3 (the query) via page 2 (the form). You have shown the code for how you are sending it from page 1 to page 2, and the code for how you are using it in page 3. If it is not there when you try to use it in page 3, then it is not getting passed from page 2 properly, and only the code on page 2 can be responsible for that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic The url sends you to a form that allows you to add your thoughts to the topic - nothing complicated there  However, this form loads a file that deals with all the processing e.g. validation and the sql query. I've added the following, however on the form: <input type = "hidden" name = "post_id" value = "$_GET['post_id'] "> That said, Im struggling to work out what  you mean by 'Then you can just get all of your values for the query from $_POST' So sorry to sound so thick - really trying

Comment: No worries. I meant that after adding that hidden input, you should be able to use `$_POST['post_id']` in your query instead of `$_GET['post_id']`.

Comment: Your hidden input needs to be like this: `<input type = "hidden" name = "post_id" value = "<?php echo $_GET['post_id']; ?> ">`. Without the php tags you will just get the string "$_GET['post_id']" rather than the actual value of that variable.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks.  No joy :( Gives me an error when I try    VALUES (' ".$_POST['email']." ', ' ".$_POST["message"]."', now(),'".$_POST['post_id']."')";
Which is weird as I only changed GET to POST and GET inserts a record into the database but with a value of 0 for post_id instead of say 5

Comment: @Don'tPanic A massive thank you for all your help however - its people like you that really help those like me, learn. Thanks

Comment: It's because you would have needed to add the `$_GET['post_id']` to the `form action` for it to be accessible, like this: `action="cwk_reply_action.php?post_id=<?=$_GET['post_id'];?>` Since the form is set to `method=post`, you have to manually add the GET string to the action, or add that data to the form as an element (as @Don'tPanic suggests).

Comment: @Jared Farrish that's it. It works!!! Many thanks!!!  Is it possible to say that both you and DontPanic solved this???

Comment: @Student there was a typo in my comment. The space before the closing quote here `value = "<?php echo $_GET['post_id']; ?> "` would mean the value would actually be `'5 '` instead of `'5'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty common type of thing for a PHP application to do. The general pattern is:

1. Pull a list of items from a database and display them with links to interact with specific items.
2. When a link is clicked, display a form with the information of the selected item.
3. When the form is submitted, save the user input to the selected item.

The minimum you need to implement this pattern is the following:

Step 1 (display the items):

```
<?php
// using mysqli for example here, but the same general idea for pdo or any other
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT id, some_text, other_columns FROM your_table WHERE criteria');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id = htmlspecialchars($row['id']);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($row['some_text']);
    echo '<a href="url/to/your_form.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $text . '</a><br>';
}
?>
```

Clicking a link (`<a>`) sends an HTTP GET request to the URL in its `href` parameter.

Step 2 (display the form):

When PHP handles the request, anything you have included in the query string of the URL (the `?id=x` portion) will be availabe in the `$_GET` array.
There are two ways you can handle this piece of data so that it can be passed on to step 3. One way is to include it in the URL in the `action` parameter of your form:

```
<form action="url/to/submission_handler.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post">
```

Another way is to include a hidden form element that contains the ID.

```
<form action="url/to/submission_handler.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">
```

Step 3 (handle the form submission):

In this step, if you have passed the ID via the `action` parameter, it will be available in the `$_GET` array (`$_GET['id']`), and if you have passed it via an input on the form, it will be available in the `$_POST` array. (`$_POST['id']`).
Either way, you should be able to access it for use in your query.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; // or $_POST['id'], depending on which way you handled it on your form

// Using a prepared statement here for example rather than concatenating values into the 
// SQL string, in order to reduce risk of SQL injection

// (Assuming $mysli is a connected mysqli object)
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE your_table SET ... WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Either method of passing the id from your form to the script that handles its submission is perfectly valid, functional and commonly used. As far as I know, which way you should do it is really just determined by your own personal preference.
But you should note that passing parameters in the query string of the `action` paramater will only work for forms with `method="post"`. If you ever need to use `method="get"` instead, only the values in the form fields will be available in `$_GET`; parameters in the query string will be ignored.
(For forms that will make changes on your server, (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` queries, writing to files, etc.) you should always be using `method="post"` anyway, but just FYI.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a variable you need it

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "post_id" value = "<?php echo $_GET['post_id']; ?> ">
```

And you will see the value of post_id

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should be more specific however your code seems pretty rusty you need someone to tell you how its done what its your current uri on this script?

its it anything like that:**http://localhost/forum.php?post_id=foobar**
Are you send a POST or a GET request? what its your enctype?
if it is you can use the $_GET super global just fine just be careful inserting it on your querys, [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) still a big problem on this day.

```
<?php  
       if ( mysqli_num_rows( $response ) >0 ) {
                while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $response, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) )
            {
                echo "<tr>
                        <th>
                        <p align = 'left'> Posted By  {$row['first_name']}  {$row['last_name']}  on  {$row['post_date']} <br/>
                        <p style = 'color:#2208A1', align='left'> 
                                        Subject: {$row['subject']} <br/><br/> Message: {$row['message']} <br/>
                                        ID Number =  {$row['post_id'] }<br/>
                        <p style='color:red;' align = 'right'>
                            <a href='http://localhost/FirstCswkAttempts/2017%20Web%20Scenario_A2/cwk_addreply.php?post_id ={$row['post_id']}'>Reply to Post.</a>
                        </p>
                     </tr>
                </th>";                       
            }

            //This is not recomenended anymore 
            //But since you are not using PDO and prepared statments its not that bad
            $email   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["message"]);
            $postId  = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['post_id']);


            //never name your variables less then 4 chars  $q = $query, $r = $response , $dbc = $databaseConnection
            $query   = "INSERT INTO responses( reply_owner, reply_text, reply_create_time, post_id ) VALUES ('$email', '$message', now(),'$postId')";
            $response = mysqli_query ( $databaseConnection, $query );
```